# ROS Jade on Ubuntu 14.04 E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full

Tags: ros, installation, ubuntu, mac, ubuntu-trusty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do these steps... I have Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty installed on a MAC PPC working perfect.

1. Made sure all Ubuntu repositories are correct.. Main, Restricted, Universe & Multiverse
2. `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'`
3. `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://pool.sks-keyservers.net --recv-key 0xB01FA116`
4. `sudo apt-get update`
5. `sudo apt-get install ros-jade-desktop-full`

This is where I get stuck with the error:

```
E: Unable to locate package ros-jade-desktop-full
```

I actually went to the "repository" directory packages.ros.org and as I browse all the folders, I ask myself. Why do I not see a package called `ros-jade-desktop-full` .. are they in a different location specified by the DBs that I find in the repository?.. or maybe I am missing something I overlooked.  I am a moderate Linux user and I don't believe I missed something, but I am new to ROS so maybe I did.

Can anyone help me to ID the issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218605/ros-jade-on-ubuntu-14.04-e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-jade-desktop-full/) by [JohnnyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/24235/johnnyq/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I have Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty installed on a **MAC PPC** working perfect.

This is the reason why you can't install ROS using the debian packages: there are no binary builds available for ROS on the PowerPC architecture (and I doubt there ever will be). Only x86, x64 and ARM-hf are currently built by the buildfarm, and for those architectures you can use the installation instructions on the wiki.

I can't actually find any explicit documentation on this ([rep-3](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html) fi doesn't mention any architectures), so it might be worthwhile to raise this issue on the [ros/rep](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep) issue tracker and / or send a mail to `ros-users` about this.

---

I'm not at all certain whether it would work, but you could try to see whether a [from source](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Source) install works. Seeing as not many packages have been run or tested on PPC recently, I would expect at least *some* difficulty getting things to work.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JohnnyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/24235/johnnyq/) on 2015-10-05**:
I understand.. well I will build an Ubuntu install on a PC Tower and go from there. I don't have too much time to waste on figuring out if they will consider an install for PPC so I will do the other.. and that way its all fresh and new. thanks

**Comment by [JohnnyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/24235/johnnyq/) on 2015-10-05**:
I wanted to add that its is strange that it won't install on an alredy working version of ubuntu on a ppc.. but oh well..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-05**:\

> [..] if they will consider an install for PPC so I will do the other [..]

I did not suggest you ask for OSRF to start building PPC binaries, I suggested reporting the issue because the documentation should explicitly state which architectures are supported, so we avoid users getting confused.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-05**:\

> I wanted to add that its is strange that it won't install on an alredy working version of ubuntu on a ppc..

It's not strange: Ubuntu and ROS are two *completely distinct* pieces of software. Canonical apparently has PPC builds of Trusty. OSRF does not do PPC builds of ROS. There is no relation.

**Comment by [JohnnyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/24235/johnnyq/) on 2015-10-05**:
Oh I did not mean due to relation, but in regards to it working under a PPC environment.  But no biggie.. you have been a great help and I do appreciate it very much.. thanks again.. peace.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-10-07**:
Question not answered anymore?

**Comment by [JohnnyQ](https://answers.ros.org/users/24235/johnnyq/) on 2015-10-11**:
Sorry.. I had taken it out till I got an answer about the binaries. They will not make binaries for PPC so I am marking this as answered.  Thanks.